# How do I clone layers in Adobe After Effects

Tags: after-effects, adobe, after-effects-expressions, after-effects-scripting

Thanks in advance for your input.
First, I have a composition that has one square in it that has opacity and scale keyframe automations.  This composition is named Square and is 25px by 25px.

Square composition is then added to another composition and is duplicated 3 times to equal 4 squares.

```
1 2
3 4
```

These 4 squares are placed in a larger square and are offset by a few frames.  This composition is named Square_4 and is 50px by 50px

I now create a new composition named Square_reveal that is 1000px by 1000px.  I want to add my Square_4 composition to Square_reveal and duplicate it so that each Square_4 layer fills the entire composition of Square_reveal.  This will be 20 Square_4 layers across (50px x 20 = 1000px across).  I then want to duplicate this row 20 times and place each row under the one above it.  This will fill the entire composition.

I have successfully done this by duplicating Square_4 20 times in one Square_reveal composition but then I have to duplicate Square_reveal 20 times and change the y position of each layer.  I feel like there could be an expression that would do this duplicating for me (400 duplicates).  If you have any idea how to do this using an expression or any other way other than manually duplicating I would appreciate your help!

Edit: My goal is to place 400 animated squares into one square  composition.  You can reference this part of the Voxyde video tutorial to see want I to accomplish.

Comment: Can you add why you're doing this? What's your goal?  Is it a multiscreen full of videos?

Comment: @tomh Please see the edit I have added added at the bottom of this question for what I am trying to replicate.  Thanks for your input.